# INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED after creating apk and INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I want to run an application via intellij IDE on my Samsung tablet I got this error:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/org......
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

I spend lots of time for googling about the problem but most of answers says: restart your device, uninstall previous version, wipe and etc

but these solutions didn't solve my problem.

The other interesting thing is that when I want to run on Emulator I got this error:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/org......
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Factory reset helped me! :(

Comment: not event factory reset! don't know what kind of problem is this, but seems to me that google should enhance their sdk/developer tools. every time I try to do something in android is a mess, hours and hours just to get it running without problems...